# Working out Ajax request in Javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making an Ajax request to server to get my data encrypted.
I am passing a Rsa publickey in the request.

Rsa publickey is

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAKO57sokSQroiScOcM3+wNuesyeccxw9WSVIwMRg2DtHsVs7PZRBgdh0
nq4IXIr/g3+LjeDRUoPWt/16oI3toqYKUX3ufyGbcr2XFt1X8okEc1jk7I8OeZ04
zYnfrz4ioyu5R4sygLBbfyxXzH2Bw7TN65kQHvybS8/ccexAfMktAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But when I make a Ajax request the publickey becomes (I have written my php code such that it store the received publick key in text file)

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAKO57sokSQroiScOcM3 wNuesyeccxw9WSVIwMRg2DtHsVs7PZRBgdh0
nq4IXIr/g3 LjeDRUoPWt/16oI3toqYKUX3ufyGbcr2XFt1X8okEc1jk7I8OeZ04 
zYnfrz4ioyu5R4sygLBbfyxXzH2Bw7TN65kQHvybS8/ccexAfMktAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

All the + characters in the key are converted to space character.
Because of this data is not getting encrypted as it requires public key to be same.

Ajax request inside javascript is

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({

url:"testrsa.php?reg="+reg+"&pass="+pass+"&reciverpubk="+alreadypubk,
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                            }).responseText;
```

variable alreadypubk contains the Rsa public key, reg and pass are the data to be encrypted.

How can I prevent replacement of + characters with space character so that my data get encrypt.

Comment: Does escaping the `+` sign work? - - It could also be that you are doing `ajax` without specifying the method. It defaults to `GET`. Also, partially unrelated, `async: false` is a bad idea. I am fairly sure the second argument of `ajax` is a callback where you can write what you want to do with the answer.

Comment: should I escape the + in actual publickey.

Comment: [Try `encodeURI()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) Or `rawurlencode` in `PHP`.

Comment: @sachinrathod You can try, and you can also try to `POST` the data instead of `GET`ting

Comment: @mayk93 I want to send data using GET. So GET being default is not an issue. And also async is false because I want other statements not to be executed untill I get a response.

Comment: @AjAX. tried both. Not working.

Comment: replace "testrsa.php?reg="+reg+"&pass="+pass+"&reciverpubk="+alreadypubk, with "testrsa.php?reg="+reg+"&pass="+pass+"&reciverpubk='"+alreadypubk+"'",

Comment: @FarhanSahibole isn't your suggestion is syntactically wrong because I am getting a javascript sysntax error.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried `escaping` the `+`.

Comment: Yes I have tried escaping the +. Still didn't get the encrypted data.

Comment: @sachinrathod You do not send data with `GET`. With `GET` you **get** data. You `POST` data when you want to send it to the server. As for `async false`, this is why you use a callback. The callback is executed when the response is received. What you are doing with `async false` is holding up your entire application, which is bad.

Comment: Try this: ```fetch(url, data)``` Where `url` is your endpoint, `localhost:8000/testrsa` for example and `data` is a object like this: ```data={ method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({key: alreadypubk}) }``` This should allow you to access `key` on the api side and read the key.

Comment: @mayk93 where should I write fetch(url,data) .  Should I include it in my ajax call.

Comment: No. `fetch` is how you should interact with a server. It does what `ajax` does, however, in most recent browsers, it is part of the standard as opposed to a external library. Open your console and write `fetch`, you should see something already defined. Here is the documentation for [fetch](https://github.github.io/fetch/) On the documentation page, you will see a example under `More comprehensive usage example` That is how you should send your key to the server. While I don't know the root cause of your problem, I am fairly certain it stems from you trying to send data url encoded.